# Windows Server 2019 unable to connect using remote desktop as administrator

Tags: windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services

We have two dedicated machines (hosted) joined to a domain, running Server 2019 Standard, serving as Session Hosts. Licensing is per user.

Machine 1 has RD Licensing, RD Connection Broker, RD Gateway, RD Web Access, Remote Apps

Machine 2 has the same, minus RD Licensing.  It uses Machine 1 for licenses.

Both machines use an alternate port for RD connections. 3389 is set to private.

machinename.domain.net SSL certificates are installed/binded to port 443 on each.

The Domain Controller (DC) is a virtual machine running Server 2016 Datacenter at a different hosting company.  (Second DC is in the process of being set up)  DC has both session host's IPs scoped in its LDAP TCP-In and UDP-In rules.

Both session hosts have the DC's IP set as the Primary DNS server in TCP/IPv4 setting.

The session hosts run several apps built in MS Access.  These are published Remote Apps.  My customers connect with their Remote App .rdp connection shortcuts.

Until mid January, this was all working great. The last few weeks we've seen sporadic RD connection issues.  Yesterday we could RD connect as local admins just fine (not using the RD Gateway).  Could not however, RD connect has domain admins or users (through the domain, gateway, etc) My customers were however, able to connect with their Remote App .rdp connection shortcuts.

Today - Can't RD connect through the domain nor as local admins. Customers can't connect with remote app .rdp shortcuts.

Local: "Can't connect to the remote computer."  Error code 0x3; Extended error code 0x7.  The events log in server manager has multiple 1306 and 1296 errors.
1306 - "Remote Desktop Connection Broker failed to redirect the user xxx\xxxxx"
1296 - "Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed while getting redirection packet from Connection Broker. User xxxx\xxxxx   Error: Remote Desktop Connection Broker is not ready for RPC communication."

Domain: "There was a problem connecting to the remote resource."  Error code 0x30000008; Extended error code 0x0.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Update: Neither session host can ping the domain controller when using the FQDN.

Comment: Are the domain controllers advertising and hosting the zone?